# How to set persistent static routes in KDE desktop system with NetworkManager and systemd?

Tags: routing, networkmanager, iproute

I have two NICs. In NetworkManager > IPv4 > Routes, I checked "ignore automatically obtained routes" for both interfaces. Then I used these two commands:

```
$ sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 metric 100 dev eth0
$ sudo ip route delete default via 192.168.2.1 dev eth1
```

The result is the routing table I wanted:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

How do I make it persistent now?

In case it matters, the configuration for eth0 is automatic (via DHCP) and for eth1 is static. Also, I'm running Arch Linux / KDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the default gateway setting for `eth1` from wherever you've added it. 
If you're unsure, run `nmcli device status`: if it says the state of `eth1` is `unmanaged`, then `eth1` is not controlled by NetworkManager at all.

A default gateway is not a mandatory configuration item for *every* network interface: you should only configure it for an interface if both a) that interface is connected to a network segment that actually contains a working router/gateway to the Internet and b) you actually want to use that interface for Internet connections.

If you want to use an interface to only access the network segment it's directly attached to, you can and should *completely omit* the default gateway setting for that interface.

If there is a router/gateway in the segment an interface is attached to, but you only have/want connectivity to a particular network segment (or segments) through it, you should instead add a more specific route entry (/entries) to specify what those segments are.

If you've configured `eth1` with NetworkManager, first run `nmcli connection show` to identify the name of the *network connection* that NetworkManager is currently using for `eth1`. Run `nmcli connection show <connection-name>` to view all the settings for that connection.

Then use e.g. `sudo nmcli connection modify <connection-name> ipv4.gateway ""` to persistently delete the spurious gateway from the static connection settings for that connection.

Then uncheck "ignore automatically obtained routes" for `eth0`, and disable & re-enable the connection for `eth0`. If your DHCP works correctly, you should now receive a default gateway through `eth0`, and as `eth1` does not currently have a default gateway, NetworkManager + your DHCP client should now automatically accept a default gateway setting from the DHCP information for `eth0`.

If your DHCP server gives you an IP address but no default gateway information for `eth0`, you should try and fix the DHCP server. If you can't do that, you can work around it by adding the missing gateway information through NetworkManager or through the configuration file of your DHCP client - but a DHCP server that doesn't give default gateway information when it should is not doing its job.